# What's the proper way to use IPv6 and IPv4 DNS resolver nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have Ubuntu 18.04, Nginx 1.17.4 VPS. This server supports IPv4 and IPv6. Although nginx.conf has only IPv4 DNS resolver. Then, I have added IPv6 to this server in following way. But there's no any backup DNS resolvers.

> resolver 1.1.1.1  [2606:4700:4700::1111] valid=10m;

I would like to know that, are there any possibility to add backup DNS address (both IPv4 and IPv6) for configuration?

Is this configuration correct?

Comment: That seems the right [syntax](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) for multiple resolvers. You can add more (separated by spaces) but please be aware that there is no such thing as "backup" resolvers,  name servers are queried in a round-robin fashion.

(*"Before version 1.1.7, only a single name server could be configured. Specifying name servers using IPv6 addresses is supported starting from versions 1.3.1 and 1.2.2."*)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. If I added [IPv4] [IPv6] [IPv4] [IPv6] DNS resolvers nginx automatically select each IPv4 and IPv6 DNS resolvers based on visitors IP address? Or I have to distinguished DNS resolvers?

Comment: @Chathu That's a good question. Did you find out?

Comment: @Houman, I use this `resolver 1.1.1.1 [2606:4700:4700::1111] 1.0.0.1 [2606:4700:4700::1001] valid=300s ipv6=on;`